# how to remove transition getting delay on read less?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using the transition effect for `Read More` & `Read Less` but on `Read Less` click transition getting delay but it's not initialized by me how can I resolve this & how to put transition effect on a gradient?

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-breeze-bbqel

Answer (score 0):

You issue not in react js itself, its on your css style

You do a transition, and transition will execute css for Pure component style every click, so that its will take 1.5 second to execute, to resolve this just add condition to transition to make its work on collapse only.

this:

```
transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
```

To this:

```
  transition: ${(props) => (props.collapse ? "" : "all 1.5s ease-in-out")};
```

you can fine solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-star-lbi9q?file=/src/ReadMoreToggler.js)

Comment: Okay did you know how could I put the transition on that gradient?